# sparklyr: select all columns except response when training model

Tags: r, sparklyr

I have a Spark DataFrame, `train_tbl`, that contains 48 different columns. I want to train a random forest model with the `sparklyr` package that uses one of the 48 columns as a `response` variable and all of the other columns as the `features`. Is there a way to specify that I want to use all fields except `loan_status` as the features, without having to type out all 47 field names?

```
ml_random_forest(x = train_tbl,
                 response = "loan_status", 
                 features = call all fields EXCEPT "loan_status",
                 num.trees = 10L,
                 type = "classification")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
ml_random_forest(x = train_tbl,
                 response = "loan_status", 
                 features = names(train_tbl)[which(names(train_tbl)!="loan_status")],
                 num.trees = 10L,
                 type = "classification")
```

Comment: @ waskuf That didn't work, but you definitely led me in the right direction...I started with your syntax for `features` and edited it to the following that worked: `colnames(train_tbl %>% select(-loan_status))`

Comment: Updated my answer, squared brackets need to be outside names(). Should work now.